# How would you bootstrap python virtualenv on RHEL5 without root access?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I know how to install the packages if I could be root, but if I can't, how would I create a virtualenv from scratch, without root access.  What are the bootstrap steps to create enough of a virtualenv to begin pip installing things.

Comment: if you have the virtualenv.py file, go to your project directory and do python virtualenv.py env.  This will create a local virtual environment. Then run it with source env/bin/activate.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, you can add --user to the installation flags for pip to install setuptools et al to your user site-packages:

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

See https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Once that's done, you can do:

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

Which will install virtualenv to your user site-packages too. From there, you can run virtualenv the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the virtualenv.py file, go to your project directory and do

```
python virtualenv.py env
```

This will create a local virtual environment. Then run it with

```
 source env/bin/activate.
```

Hope that helps!